# How do solve this serious issue concerning folders in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, virus

My PC is totally functional. Except two/three issues, which may be connected to each other or might be mutually exclusive.

1. I cannot create a new folder anywhere. Not in desktop, not under another folder. The "Create Folder" option is simply missing.
2. I cannot open a folder directly. Whenever I double-click on a folder, I see the message below. However, when I right-click the folder and select the option "Open in New Window", it works just fine! I can the see the contents of the folder normally in the new window.
3. When I right click, there is an option called "cmd". I have no idea how it came.

   How do I get rid of the problem? Is there any way? Please help. I could not post images because my rep level is below 10.

Comment: post image as link via upload site and someone will upload them for you

Comment: See this accepted answer, let us know if it works, I have used it in the past with success....https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/97de8a2a-12f2-4381-a409-a78f4ae551cf/cannot-create-new-folder-in-windows-7?forum=w7itprogeneral

Comment: @Moab I just formatted the computer with Windows disk.

Answer (score 0):

First: check filesystem on your system drive. In elevated cmd run `chkdsk c: /f` and allow to run checkdisk after reboot.
Second: check the folder permission in `C:\Users` folder related to  your windows account. You should have a write permission on this and sub-folders.